# Opening terminal tabs through SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal, session

I am connecting to a linux machine exclusively over SSH. Recently I noticed that no matter what process is running in terminal, every time I close and reconnect through SSH the process may or may not still be running but I still get a fresh terminal instance over SSH and can't access the old one.

So this isn't the actual problem, because what I want is to be able to open another tab (or an equivalent) in the terminal my SSH connection already opened. So I can start e.g. a daemon there and switch to that tab to check on its status while I do different things in the main tab. Is there a possibility like this?

Note however: I connect from an SSH client on my Android phone. So I can't just open another tab there by typing `xterm &` or something similar that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a terminal multiplexing program, like `screen` or `tmux` to have more than one terminal session open on one connection.

Another benefit from those, is that the session remains if the connection gets interrupted.

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

https://tmux.github.io/

Comment: Yes, but they only are usable with a GUI aren't they?

Comment: No, these are CLI programs, so all you need is a terminal access.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. I am currently downloading tmux.

Comment: By the way, your distribution's repositories should have at least one of those programs available. Check your package manager, before manually installing anything.