# ssh: subscribe to nohup.out

Tags: ssh, nohup

Suppose I launch a long running task on a remote machine with `nohup`:

```
nohup command &
```

Is there a way for me to stream the contents of `nohup.out` to a terminal with `ssh` such that it is getting updated as `nohup.out` is published to?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358255/opening-terminal-tabs-through-ssh/

Comment: is there any reason why simply `ssh user@host tail -f nohup.out` won't work?

Comment: @mosvy nope that sounds like it’ll work* (sneezed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `tail -f` on `nohup.out` as mentioned in the comments. But for a long running task, you might be better off running it under [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (or tmux). It allocates a virtual terminal where the command can run, allowing you to disconnect and reconnect to the "session" at will.

Inside screen, you can just run your command and have the last output visible on the terminal, or e.g. run `mycmd > outputfile` to save the output to a file, or even `mycmd | tee outputfile` to get the output both to a terminal, and a file. And screen even allows you to open multiple windows, so you can easily browse the output file while the command runs.

Comment: `</advertisement>`

Comment: ah thanks man.  This is a good answer, and I'm making heavy use of tmux.  for this particular scenario, am looking just to checkout nohup.out intermittently for debug output.